# Python: bitly request

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to do a basic Bitly shortening URL call. However, I cannot seem to either push the json correctly, or deal with the json response correctly... I omitted some obvious variables for brevity and obfuscated some real values for security purposes.

```
import requests
import json
bitly_header = {'Authorization':'Bearer 
                some_long_secret_character_string_here', 'Content-Type':'application/json'}

bitly_data = {
        "long_url": ""+long_url+"",
        "group_guid": ""+bitly_guid+""
       }
short_link_resp =requests.post(bitly_endpoint,data=bitly_data,headers=bitly_header)
short_link_json = short_link_resp.json()
short_link = short_link_json["link"]
```

Errors is "Key error: 'link'

The json I get from Postman is:

```
{
    "created_at": "1970-01-01T00:00:00+0000",
    "id": "bit.ly/2MjdrrG",
    "link": "bit.ly/2MjdrrG",
    "custom_bitlinks": [],
    "long_url": "google.com/",
    "archived": false,
    "tags": [],
    "deeplinks": [],
    "references": {
        "group": "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/groups/Bi7i8IbM1x9"
    }
}
```

Comment: try replace `data` with `json`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!  Now - how do I mark your post as the "answer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replace `data` with `json`:

```
short_link_resp =requests.post(bitly_endpoint, json=bitly_data, headers=bitly_header)
```

see the [doc ref](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).